# Sandbox Paypal Invoice API, email not sent

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I try to implement an invoice service with paypal invoice api.
Everything work, but the invoice mail is not sent, is it normal ? maybe on sandbox email is not sent ?

Thx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The email does not go to an outward facing email. It will go to the notifications section under the email address of the account you are trying to receive the email from [image: screen shot of notifications]

Comment: I can't find this section in my paypal backoffice, can you be more specifique ? Anyway on a production environement i suppose email are sent ?

Comment: login to developer.paypal.com > Applications > Sandbox accts > drop down icon next to the email address > notificaitons

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone comes back to this topic.  You can also get the link to the invoice by using the 'share link' action within invoice management.  This will give you the link to the invoice.  You can also just add the encrypted invoice ID to this URL www.paypal.com/invoice/payerView/details/INV2-####-####-####-####